# Python: Create a user and send email with account details to the user

Tags: python, linux, email

Here is a script I have written which will create a new user account. I am trying to get help in adding a bit more to it.

I want to have it also send an email to the new user that is created. Ideally, the program will ask the user creating the new account, what their email is, and then it will use the user and password variables and send an email to that new user so they will know how to log in. What would be the best way to do this, thanks for any advice.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import commands, os, string
import sys
import fileinput


def print_menu():       ## Your menu design here
    print 20 * "-" , "Perform Below Steps to Create a New TSM Account." , 20 * "-"
print "1. Create User Account"
print 67 * "-"

loop=True      

while loop:          ## While loop which will keep going until loop = False
    print_menu()    ## Displays menu
    choice = input("Enter your choice [1-5]: ")

    if choice==1:
        user = raw_input("Enter the Username to be created: " )
        password = raw_input( "Enter the password for the user: "  )
        SRnumber = raw_input( "Enter the Service Request Number: ")

        user = user + " "

        output = os.system('create user' + user)
        output = os.system('set password' + password)
```

Comment: @MooingRawr Not True. In python 2.7 input() takes everything. when you pass it 5, it will return an int. You can even pass it python code.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily send mails with gmail and smtplib (you maybe need to install it first). This way you can send any message you want.

```
import smtplib

toaddrs = raw_input('what is your e mail?')
fromaddr = 'youremail@email.com'

msg = 'the message you want to send'
server.starttls()
server.login(fromaddr, "your gmail password")
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

You will have to allow less secure apps in your gmail settings.